# How to hide xAxis category of a hidden series in highcharts boxplot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, boxplot

I'm trying to hide a certain series by clicking on the legend item and/or using the `hide()` method. The series gets hidden, but the category is still visible on the xAxis. In some other solutions for other charts, [like this column chart solution](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ydc7wyz8/1/), breaks were suggested, but that doesn't work on the boxplot chart. Only the leftmost and rightmost categories get hidden. Here's a jsfiddle of the boxplot that's not working:

https://jsfiddle.net/mjan7y48/

In the same application I have a column chart that hides its category immediately without any trouble. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing Highstock solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `grouping` for this solution to work:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        grouping: false,
        ...
    },
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w6nhvge7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.grouping

Comment: Thanks, your example made me find the way to solve the issue. It's not about grouping, but about Highstock. ImportingHighstock to my code solved the issue.